# Heroku /Django What can i remove from requirements.txt or how to handle my error

Tags: django, git, heroku, push-notification

i got a problem with pushing my Django project on Heroku. a get an error :

```
could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement codeville==0.8.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
no distribution at all found for  codeville==0.8.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

my requirements.txt have been generated by `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and it looks that:

```
Codeville==0.8.0
Mako==0.7.2

MarkupSafe==0.15
PIL==1.1.7
Pygments==1.5
Pyrex==0.9.9
Twisted==12.3.0
bsddb3==5.3.0
bzr==2.6b2
bzr-fastimport==0.13.0.final.0
chardet==2.0.1
cvs2svn==2.4.0
dblatex==0.3.4
distribute==0.6.34
fastimport==0.9.2
feedparser==5.0.1
gdata==2.0.17
getmail==4.36.0
googlecl==0.9.14
logilab-astng==0.23.1
logilab-common==0.58.0
mercurial==2.5.2
mingc==0.4.4
numpy==1.6.2
offlineimap==6.5.4
paramiko==1.7.7.1
planet==2.0
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pyasn1==0.1.6
pycrypto==2.6
pygobject==3.4.2
pylint==0.25.1
pyxdg==0.25
rdiff-backup==1.2.8
spambayes==1.0.4
stgit==0.16
tailor==0.9.35
urlgrabber==3.1.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==4.0.3
```

Codeville is first on the list, and i assume that this problem will continue with other lines, so how should i handle it??  i dont have time for removing one by one and checking if it works, couse every time its uploading and my project weighs  >30mb

Comment: This might not be ideal, but you could clone codeville's code into a github repo and satisfy the dependency that way. It's not the "right way" to do things though.

Comment: Are you using that app? or is a app requirement? try delete from there? I can found that app in Pypi, maybe it doesn't exist any more

Comment: What is `Codeville` I could not find a 3rd party app by that name on the internet

Comment: codeVille is not the only one, i tried to remove most of entries in requirements.txt  .... so only solution you know is adding apps to internal project? That make sens ^^   if they dont support server by thoose modules, i'll have to include them in project..